# How can I pass file with resolveLocalFilesystemUrl and read it to upload picture IN IONIC 3

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, promise

I am trying to upload pictures to my server in IONIC 3, but Sometimes it functions well and sometines not. I think is for the syncrony .

The flow is :

In my Page i have button where it take the picture and save the photo( this step function good).

1. take picture

> ```
> takePhoto() {
>     this.camera.getPicture({
>       quality: 80,
>       destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
>       targetWidth: 150,
>       targetHeight: 150,
>       correctOrientation: true
>     }).then(imageUri => {
>       this.myPhoto = imageUri;
>       }).catch(error => console.warn(error))
>   }
> ```

Then when i have this picture and The button send photo is available , if i Click in this button , the next stept is the next :

```
 private uploadPhoto(): void {
    if (this.myPhoto != undefined || !this.myPhoto || this.myPhoto != null) {
      let imageFileUri = this.myPhoto;
      this.error = null;
      this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: 'Cargando imagen...'
      });
      this.loading.present();

      this.file.resolveLocalFilesystemUrl(imageFileUri)
        .then(entry => (<FileEntry>entry).file(file => this.readFile(file)))
        .catch(err => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(err));
        });
    }
    else {
      this.presentAlertFailText("No hay ninguna imagen", "Selecciona una e inténtalo de nuevo.")
    }
  }
```

and this function call the next, where i call to my service to upload to my server .

```
private readFile(file: any) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = () => {
            const formData = new FormData();
            const imgBlob = new Blob([reader.result], {type: file.type});
            formData.append('profile', imgBlob, file.name);          
            this._up.uploadUserPicture(formData).then(res => {
                localStorage.setItem('PHOTO', res['result']);
                this.loading.dismiss();              

            }, err => {
                this.loading.dismiss();
                this.presentToast('Imagen no subida');                
            }).catch(err => {
                this.loading.dismiss();
                this.presentToast('Imagen no subida');                
            })
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    }
```

I think the problem is for the promises, for this reason sometimes function well and sometimes not.

I think i need refactor the code in the line : 
 .then(entry => (entry).file(file => this.readFile(file)))
in function uploadPhoto

But i don't know ..how can i do that .
Do you have any suggestion ?[picture of my page with flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjYeo.png)

Comment: It would be very simple if you organised your code better. `uploadPhoto` doesn't upload anything, but instead calls `readFile`, which which calls `uploadUserPicture`. And `resolveLocalFilesystemUrl` should also be inside `readFile`. Then flow would be like this `uploadPhoto = { readFile.then(uploadUserPicture) ) }`

Comment: @dfsq UploadPhoto is called for button Upload, and this button is active when this.myPhoto has value, I've posted picture in the question, see please

Comment: @dfsq Please, could you help me to re-write the code , I dont understand uploadPhoto = { readFile.then(uploadUserPicture) ) }